# Best way to export CSV string through JSON via WebAPI?

Tags: string, csv, .net-core, compression, stringbuilder

Have been stringbuilding CSV files for ages on MVC applications just fine, until now.
One mistake made me generate a CSV string bigger then the system can handle in memory, so i have been searching the web for any solution on minifing a string that could be reconstructed back on client.

So far i have been doing this:

```
StringBUilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(stuff in manyEnumerableStuff)
    sb.Append(stuff);

return csv.ToString().ToBase64();

public static string ToBase64(this string value) => Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value));
```

The application can handle `.ToString()` in this HUGE case just "fine", but it fails without creating excpetions at `.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value));`

This only happens on huge strings because from what i know, base64 will make the string 33% bigger.

Compressed json can't solve this problem, since this happens on server side.

So I have gonne on search to minify or compress this string, but it still need to be a string and can be converted on client site Angular application.

I have found this:

```
        public static string compress(this string big) {
            var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(big);

            using (var msi = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            using (var mso = new MemoryStream()) {
                using (var gs = new GZipStream(mso, CompressionMode.Compress)) {
                    //msi.CopyTo(gs);
                    CopyTo(msi, gs);
                }

                return mso.ToArray().ToString();
            }
        }   

        private static void CopyTo(Stream src, Stream dest) {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];

            int cnt;

            while ((cnt = src.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0) {
                dest.Write(bytes, 0, cnt);
            }
        }
```

but I think there is no sense at all, because i can't put byte[] on json value as string without converting it back.

Is it possible to compress plain Pipe separated values that represents a .CSV file after getting the string from `StringBuilder()`?

I have tried `GC.collect()` right after parsing SB to string but still broke the application.

I'm on .Net Core 2.1, Linux server.

Comment: Just want do add that I have solved my problem looking into an incorrect loop which was duplicating unnecessary data, but still, I would not know how to solve this problem, if I actually had a file that big.